# Creating N-ary Expression Tree from List definition

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree, expression-trees

Code newbie here, and I am creating a project in Python.

I have a class called ExpressionTree which is, an N-ary expression tree, such that each node is not merely restricted to having only two children; it can have more than 2, but not less than 2.

The class's private variables are: `_root` which is `Optional[Union[str, int]]` and `_subtrees` which is `List[ExpressionTree]`. I have successfully implemented basic methods such as __eq__, is_empty, evaluate_tree, __str__, and append, but I am stuck permanently on one single method.

The only operators I would use in this tree are "+" and "-" (but the code should work for any operator).

All leaves are either a single letter string, or an integer, and all parents are either "+" or "-". Also, all leaves are ExpressionTrees but with an empty list for self._subtrees.

The method I am trying to create is called create_tree, which takes in a list called lst, for which the type is: List[List[Union[int, str]]], and returns a successfully created ExpressionTree that was made from the parameter: lst.

Each list in lst represents a level, but for each operator in the list, the next lists are the children of each operator. For example, if `lst = [[+], [+, +], [1, 2], [3, 4]]`, then the Tree should look something like:

[Tree 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKP4i.png)

On a more nested example, if I were to run `create_tree([[+], [3, +, +], [5, *], [b, c], [6, a]])`, the Tree I should be getting is:

[Tree 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHDKP.png)

I know that a Queue would be very useful, but I do not know where to start.
I don't think this code necessarily would need recursion, but it could work with it as well if implemented correctly.

I wish not to use any imports or create new classes, except List.

The doctest I have are something like this:

```
>>> lst = [['*'], [3, '*' , '*'], [5, 1], ['b', 'c']]
>>> express_tree = create_tree(lst)
>>> print(express_tree) == (3 * (5 * 1) * (b * c))
True
>>> express_tree._root == '*'
True
>>> express_tree._subtrees == [ExpressionTree(3, []), 
                               ExpressionTree('*', [ExpressionTree(5, []), 
                                                    ExpressionTree(1, [])]), 
                               ExpressionTree('*', [ExpressionTree('b', []), 
                                                    ExpressionTree('c', [])])]
True
```

I have spent the past 12 hours trying to correctly implement this, and I have had no luck, and I think my brain is not working properly.
Any help with the code is immensely appreciated.
Please help this poor fellow so I can get out of this nightmare of a class and work on more enjoyable coding projects.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of what you've tried so far for `create_tree()`, and where it's failing?

Comment: In the beginning of the method, I can handle cases when lst is empty to return an empty ExpressionTree `return ExpressionTree(None, [])` , and when lst is a double nested list of an integer or alphabet to return an expression tree with that aforementioned integer or alphabet as root with empty list as _subtrees `return ExpressionTree(lst[0][0], [])`. I can't pinpoint where it is failing, but I am using BFS, where I add the children for the first list, and if a children _root is '+' or '*', I add the nest list(s) into each operators, and so on.

Comment: The big problem is that usually what happens is the recursive process doesn't realize that the next list might not be for them to use to create _subtrees, so the entire Tree is just jumbled. I've tried to change the code so that I keep pointers on where it should look for _subtrees, but it never works no matter how I implement it. There probably is a way to do it in numerous ways, but I'm just a bad programmer after all.

Comment: I also tried to do some research on similar issues on the internet but most of the issues are for binary expression trees, and the list type I use as a parameter is not very often used, moreso never. I still don't want to give up yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the recursive function, the tree can be built by passing the formed levels to `ExpressionTree`:

```
class ExpressionTree:
   def __init__(self, _root, _subtrees):
      self._root, self._subtrees = _root, _subtrees
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self._root}, {self._subtrees})'

def to_tree(d):
   k = [ExpressionTree(i, [] if i not in {'+', '*'} else d.pop(0)) for i in d.pop(0)]
   for i in range(len(k)):
      if k[i]._root in {'+', '*', '-'}: 
         d = [k[i]._subtrees, *d]
         if len(d) == 1:
            k[i]._subtrees = [ExpressionTree(i, []) for i in k[i]._subtrees]
         else:
            k[i]._subtrees = to_tree(d)
   return k


lst = [['*'], [3, '*' , '*'], [5, 1], ['b', 'c']]
lst1 = [['+'], ['+', '+'], ['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
lst2 = [['+'], ['3', '+', '+'], ['5', '*'], ['b', 'c'], ['6', 'a']]
lst3 = [['+'], ['3', 'c', '+'], ['5', 'a']]
for i in [lst, lst1, lst2, lst3]:
   print(to_tree(i))
   print('-'*20)
```

Output:

```
[ExpressionTree(*, [ExpressionTree(3, []), ExpressionTree(*, [ExpressionTree(5, []), ExpressionTree(1, [])]), ExpressionTree(*, [ExpressionTree(b, []), ExpressionTree(c, [])])])]
--------------------
[ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(1, []), ExpressionTree(2, [])]), ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(3, []), ExpressionTree(4, [])])])]
--------------------
[ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(3, []), ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(5, []), ExpressionTree(*, [ExpressionTree(6, []), ExpressionTree(a, [])])]), ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(b, []), ExpressionTree(c, [])])])]
--------------------
[ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(3, []), ExpressionTree(c, []), ExpressionTree(+, [ExpressionTree(5, []), ExpressionTree(a, [])])])]
--------------------
```